# Difficulty when using APIs in the support library in the new version of the SDK

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I’m a little turned around by what I’m reading and the errors that are occurring when I set the minSDK level to 4. You would think that when a new version of the platform is generated, it would be backward compatible with earlier versions; so if I create software in SDK 17, using its features will work on devices using an earlier version such as 4, or whatever. But this doesn’t seem to be the case. Since I’ve bought a phone running version 2.3.6… of the android OS I would like to make sure the software I’m developing works on this and other older devices, as well as the newer OSs.  But it doesn’t seem like backward compatibility is guaranteed. So, does one just develop for newer devices, or is there a way to ensure that what I write in the new environment will work on devices without having to jump through a bunch of hoops? I’m trying to use the support library, but it doesn’t seem to have all the apis of the newer versions. Can one just import the needed apis into the support library in some way? And if so, can you point me to an article on doing that?

I’m trying to create an app that has tabs in the action bar, using both activities and fragments and I keep getting version mismatch errors, stating something like, “the minimum SDK level is 4. It should be 13".

I’m pretty certain I can get the app to work for newer devices, but I’m sure all potential users won’t have a new phone. So, I’m seeking your insights on getting around what I see as an ongoing issue.

Your insights are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> You would think that when a new version of the platform is generated, it would be backward compatible with earlier versions; so if I create software in SDK 17, using its features will work on devices using an earlier version such as 4, or whatever

Features that *existed* in API Level 4 generally exist in API Level 17, and the code supporting those features is generally backwards compatible.

However, newer versions of Android have *additional features*. Those are not necessarily backwards compatible, as by definition, they are newer and additional.

> So, does one just develop for newer devices, or is there a way to ensure that what I write in the new environment will work on devices without having to jump through a bunch of hoops?

One can most certainly develop apps that work on older devices and newer ones. APIs that exist on older and newer devices, you just use, typically without issue. APIs that exist only on newer devices you have to take care to not try using those capabilities on older devices. There are a variety of techniques for doing this, such as by examining `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and skipping the newer API stuff on older devices.

Since there is no canonical definition of "jump through a bunch of hoops", you will need to decide that for yourself. It does require you to be capable of reading documentation, as there is quite a bit of it on how to build backwards-compatible applications, such as [this discussion of developing backwards-compatible UIs](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html). There are also plenty of blog posts and the like covering specific aspects of backwards compatible development, available via your favorite search engine.

> I’m trying to use the support library, but it doesn’t seem to have all the apis of the newer versions

It is not supposed to, nor has it been advertised as having that. It has backports of some things, but not everything. Partly, that is simply a question of engineering time. Partly, that is because some things just cannot be backported, because they are core changes to the OS, not merely framework classes.

> I’m trying to create an app that has tabs in the action bar, using both activities and fragments and I keep getting version mismatch errors, stating something like, “the minimum SDK level is 4. It should be 13".

As abbath noted, the action bar is not part of the Android Support package, though [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) fills that role. Similar backports are available for other things not found in the Android Support package and can be found on such sites as [AndroidViews.net](http://www.androidviews.net/).

Answer (score 2):

ActionBar is introduced not so long ago, that's why you need API level 13 to use it.

If you want to use an ActionBar with tabs, but also want to develop for lower sdk versions, try to use a compability library, such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: @abbaath I've imported the ActionBarSherlock project, and followed the video @ the site. But I get errors in the project that aren't cleared when I attempt to pull in the support library. Any suggestions?